# Reusing older raid discs

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I have a software RAID5 array (Linux md) on 4 disks; the OS is OpenSUSE 12.3.

Recently I replaced a disc with a larger one (fail disc, remove it, add new disc). The capacity of the array has not yet increased as I didn't replace all discs. Now the new one seems to be bad and I want to replace it with the old one. Can I simply remove the new one (fail, remove) and replace it with the unchanged old one or should I format the old one before adding it to the array? The array has a bitmap.

What would happen if I simply shut down the machine and replaced the discs without using `mdadm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the bitmap has not changed when the old disk was replaced by the new one, it should work to mark the disk as failed and remove it from the array.

```
mdadm -f /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
mdadm -r /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
```

Then replace the disk and add the old one to the array:

```
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sde1
```

I think that shutting down the machine and replacing the disks would also work, but the `mdadm` method has the advantage that the disks can be hot-plugged if supported by the machine.

Comment: Hot-plugging is not supported by the hardware.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I think it will be safer to remove the disk using mdadm, then add the old disk and let the array rebuild itself.

Comment: Will the bitmap be used then to speed the rebuild?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Yes, the bitmap should speed up rebuilding the array.